# How to translate variables?

Tags: twig, translation, symfony4

I'm translating a variable to create a translatable link in my template.
This is in my twig template, which works.

```
{{ 'Click this %link% for more info.'|trans({'%link%': '<a href="#">' ~ 'link'|trans ~ '</a>'})|raw }}
```

However, after I update my translation files (.xlf) it just shows this string:

Click this %link% for more info.

Here's my translation update command:

```
bin/console translation:update --force fr
```

Here's my translation file:

```
<trans-unit id="XrWqVVg" resname="Click this %link% for more info.">
        <source>Click this %link% for more info.</source>
        <target>Click this %link% for more info.</target>
      </trans-unit>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

intl-icu.xlf files do not understand %% variables. They use {}.

```
<trans-unit id="XrWqVVg" resname="Click this link for more info.">
        <source>Click this link for more info.</source>
        <target>Click this {link} for more info.</target>
      </trans-unit>
```